# Google font not loading in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, google-fonts

I'm kinda new to WordPress custom theme building and I have a problem.

I have a google font Poppins and I have put the code in head.php:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="preload stylesheet" as="style">
```

when I open the network tab I see that they have indeed loaded:

[see network tab here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ4Am.png)

I see the font being loaded on my computer but when I open it on some other device the font is not loaded. Some help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" media="screen">
```

Also, if you have loaded the site/page previously on the other devices, make sure you clear cache.